# SOAP fault response also showing the request in the SOAP body

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, soapfault

When we requesting the SOAP web service with wrong data, the fault message is coming properly, but along with that the requested data are also coming under the SOAP body, How can I make only fault section coming under the SOAP body?  I do not want the request data in the SOAP body along withe fault details

Comment: Can you show the implementation of your service? So it's easier to identify the problem (if any).